# Reading remote CSV with Node JS

Tags: javascript, node.js, csv

I have the following problem: I'm trying to read a remote CSV from another website, and whenever I use a http.get, I get a status code 410 Gone. Chrome can download it just fine, also the other site loads these CSVs as well.

```
var options = {
    host: myHost,
    port: 80,
    path: myURL,
    method: 'GET',
    headers: {
        'Content-disposition': 'attachment; filename='someFile.csv',
        'Content-Type': 'text/csv'
    }
};

http.get(options, function(res) {
    var str = '';
    res.on('data', function(chunk) {
        str += chunk;
    });
    res.on('end', function() {
        console.log(str);
    });
});
```

I tried using require, but I get the same thing. What's the proper way to go about this?

Answer (score 0):

I don't know if this is the main cause of your problem or not, but both the headers you are sending are not appropriate for a GET request.

`Content-disposition` is a response header.  It only really has meaning in the response.  Here's a description of this header from MDN:

> In a regular HTTP response, the Content-Disposition response header is a header indicating if the content is expected to be displayed inline in the browser, that is, as a Web page or as part of a Web page, or as an attachment, that is downloaded and saved locally.

`Content-type`, when used in a request, describes the content format of the data you are sending with the request.  This is appropriate for a POST or a PUT, but not for a GET since with a GET you aren't sending any data other than the request headers itself and the path.

If a request wants to send a preferred content-type to the server for a GET request, it would generally either use the Accept header to list its preferred data types or it would use a query parameter that the server is known to support to communicate the desired data type.  You can see a discussion of `Content-type` and `Accept` headers in [this post](https://webmasters.stackexchange.com/questions/31212/difference-between-the-accept-and-content-type-http-headers).

If removing these does not make a difference, then there must be some other difference in your GET request vs. what the browser sends.  You can tell for sure what is different by examining both requests.  If you control the server, then you can use one of the packet sniffers that will show you exactly what the incoming HTTP request is in both cases and you can compare them directly.  If you don't control the server, then you can use such a packet sniffer on the client-side and look at both outgoing requests.  In the browser, you can see the request in the network tab of the browser debugger.

A 4xx error implies that there's something wrong with the resource specification and the server doesn't think it can find a matching resource.  That could either be triggered by one of the above two headers unexpectedly being present or it would more likely be an issue with the path specification in the request.

One other thing to check is whether the browser is also sending a cookie to this server that might contain some other information relevant to the request (such as a username or something like that).  We could help in more detail if we could see exactly what was in both requests on the wire and see how they differ.

---

Though this is probably not what is happening in your case, it would also be advisable to have an HTTP error handler:

```
http.get(options, function(res) {
    var str = '';
    res.on('data', function(chunk) {
        str += chunk;
    });
    res.on('end', function() {
        console.log(str);
    });
}).on('error', function(e) {
    // error sending the request here
    console.log(e);
});
```

Comment: I have removed the headers from options, and added the error handling. However my problem remains. Unfortunately I don't control the other server. When I access the link from chrome e.g.  http://ctpcj.ro/orare/csv/orar_4_lv.csv I get this in the developer console: Resource interpreted as Document but transferred with MIME type text/csv: "http://ctpcj.ro/orare/csv/orar_4_lv.csv". The page still loads, but the file gets also downloaded.

Comment: @StirZoltán - When I try to access that link in Chrome, it does not work for me.  I get a message about a 410 error.

Comment: Hmm. It seems like that there is a cookie or something because if I open it in a different browser it doesn't work. I forgot to mention, that this file might be behind some sort of content management system(it looks like it's joomla)

Comment: @StirZoltán - You can look at the network tab in the Chrome debugger and see exactly what is being sent with the browser request (including any cookies).  I'm guessing you must have logged in at some point in the browser and it created a cookie.

Comment: @StirZoltán - Did this answer your question?

Comment: Unfortunately no. It looks like the csv is protected somehow by the cms. I couldn't find anything helpful that is being sent to grant me access.

Comment: @StirZoltán - Is there a login session cookie that you're missing in order to get access?  My previous comment suggested you examine the exact http request coming from the browser (when it works) to see what your node.js request may be missing.